# Haskell beginner trying to find the syntax errors

Tags: haskell, implicit

```
N = a ’div’ length xs
    where
      a = 10
     xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I am currently learning Haskell and I got a task in which I have to find the syntax errors and try to fix them. I can see **`div`** needs to be enclosed with backquotes. However, I am not sure if there are any other errors?

Comment: These are "forward quotes", not backticks.

Comment: also the `xs = ` line needs to be indented by one more space so that it's in line with the definition above (if you care about keeping the `=` signs in line, as some do, then just introduce an extra space after the `a`)

Comment: A compiler would tell you if there are other errors.

Comment: voting to close, "caused by a typo"

Answer (score 4):

There are many errors in the code:

```
N = a ’div’ length xs
    where
      a = 10
     xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

- `div` needs to be enclosed in backquotes.
- `xs` in line 4 needs to be aligned with `a` in order to say that it is part of the same code block
- Function names in Haskell must start with a lower case letter

Comment: It seems I got a "parse error on input ‘=’ "  after the change.

Answer (score 3):

There are three problems here:

1. you use an [*apostrophe* `’` [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) instead of [*backticks* `` ` `` [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming);
2. you need to indent `a` and `xs` on the same column; and
3. the name of functions starts with a lowercase, so `n` instead of `N`:

```
--    🖟   🖟 backticks
n = a `div` length xs
    where
      a = 10
      xs = [1,2,3,4,5]  -- 🖘 same indentation as a
```

Comment: Function names cannot start with a capital letter...

Comment: @FrancisKing: thanks, updated.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: It seems I got a "parse error on input ‘=’ "  after the change.

Comment: @sctts-lol: likely that is because of a function *before* this one that has invalid syntax.